# Vertical redstone crossroads

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have 2 redstone signals that are unavoidably going to cross each other vertically (i.e. One is horizontal and the other moves vertically through it).

I ideally need a way to have these signals pass through each other without any signal pollution.

If this is not possible in a 1 block wide space then I can find some other way of creating this circuit but if there is a way that will work in a tiled design then I'd like a schematic such as those created at http://mordritch.com/mc_rss/.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:
Schematic of what I had for 1 layer. I'm only space limited in that this needs to be tile-able in a row of directly adjacent copies or a repeating pattern of 2.
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid not as I've changed it whilst testing other possibilities but I'll put up a schematic

Comment: Is there no way you can go around them? How much space do you have to work with?

Comment: Fairly large area but only 1 block wide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have come up with a working design using slimeblocks:

[image: Screenshot showing the design]

The vertical line is done using a sticky piston pushing slime blocks up and down. You'll need three slime blocks to prevent the horizontal line from powering the piston due to quasi-connectivity.

The horizontal line crosses the slime blocks. The repeater has to be placed on the far side of the redstone blocks, and set to two ticks. This prevents the signal from turning off while the slimeblocks are moved. Thanks to [ash4fun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/141451/ash4fun) for the idea with the higher repeater delay.

Comment: This is great. But is there a way of removing the tiny off moment but not have the signal fade as when I want it iff it needs to turn off in one go

Comment: @OlieAyre not that I know of, no (didn't think about it for too long though). I'm not sure I understand your design correctly, but you If I do, you can put a dot of redstone dust next to the comparator, place a second comparator facing into that dust next to one of the blocks and a container (furnace is usually good) next to that. This will make the comparator signal turn off more quickly (needs to be stable for 2 ticks I believe). I think this will be fine with your tiling, the next line will get the same signal strength from this sideline.

Comment: Or I could use a pulse extender to knock it up 2 ticks or so.

Comment: would it work to simply give the repeater 3 ticks of delay?

Comment: @ash4fun uhh... that should actually work, and is much better than what I did (it was late when I wrote this answer, I blame that).

Comment: @ash4fun it works indeed. Setting the repeater to two ticks is sufficient. I have changed the answer to use that instead of the clunky comparator thingy. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

If you **can use OP** for your task, you can use (probably server-lighter solution than plain Redstone) **commandblocks**.

The good thing about it is that you are not limited by one line, you can transfer redstone wirelessly on longer distance or so. And you won't interact with the second line at all.

You just need to use negating rs torch and two commands:

```
    R C
    B
    R C
...>B
```

where B = solid block, R = redstone torch, C = command block, ...> incoming redstone signal

All you need is to place this command into commandblocks:

Upper CB:

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> minecraft:redstone_block
```

lower CB:

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> minecraft:stone
```

From XYZ coords you can then connect your next redstone.
This should work on even long distances, if both locations are in loaded chunks. You can also revert the redstone if needed, just by switching the commands.

Comment: A [minecraft-redstone] tag without a [minecraft-commands] tag usually means that the asker wants a survival-freindly solution

Comment: That's why there is IF on start of question. A lot of mapmakers usually do use commandblocks, so mentioning about this method can help someone , or the asker, too.

Comment: This would be the perfect solution and I can use command blocks but I just don't want to. I'd much rather spend 2 weeks making all this amazing redstone that fits together really well and looks awesome and is a genuine engineering challenge than 2 hours setting up command blocks.